# HTML5 Canvas rotate function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, rotatetransform

```
function drawNumbers(){
    var rad, num;

    cx.font= "30px Arial";
    cx.textAlign = "center";
    cx.textBaseline = "middle";

    //numbers around the inner circumference
     for(num=1; num < 13; num++){
    rad = num * Math.PI/6; //angle for every number
     cx.rotate(rad);
     cx.translate(0, -175);
     cx.rotate(-rad);
     cx.fillText(num.toString(),0,0);
     cx.rotate(rad);
     cx.translate(0, 175);
     cx.rotate(-rad);
    }
}

function drawHands(){
    //getting the time
    var time = new Date();
    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds();

    //setting the radians based on the time
    //hour hand
    hours %= 12;
    hours = (hours * Math.PI/6) + (minutes * Math.PI/360) + (seconds * Math.PI/21600);
    hands(hours, radius * 0.04, radius * 0.5);

    //minute hand
    minutes = (minutes * Math.PI/30) + (seconds * Math.PI/1800);
    hands(minutes, radius * 0.03, radius * 0.65);

    //second hand
    seconds = (seconds * Math.PI/30);
    hands(seconds, radius * 0.01, radius * 0.68);
}

function hands(ang, width, length){
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = width;
    cx.lineJoin = "round";
    cx.lineCap = "round";
    cx.moveTo(0, 0);
    cx.rotate(ang);
    cx.lineTo(0, -length);
    cx.stroke();
    cx.rotate(-ang);
}
```

I was learning the HTML5 canvas in W3Schools and the tutorial was teaching how to make a working clock.
1. I just don't understand how the extra rotates work in the functions. 
2. When applying a rotate function, does it always rotate from the center of origin (0, 0) of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `rotate` function it rotates the entire canvas, imagine holding a painting and then tilting it. It happens around the origin always. The way to rotate around a different point is to `translate` the entire canvas first, then `rotate` it.

Going back to the painting analogy, if we have rotated our painting, once we have drawn our line, we need to then restore the painting to being upright. Thus we `rotate(-ang)`. If we had translated we would also have to undo our transation in a similar manner.

### Rotating and why we undo rotates

In the code below you can see I'm drawing a base black rectangle, and then calling a function which rotates the canvas by 0.5 radians and draws another rectangle twice. I haven't undone my rotation so the 3rd rectangle is actually rotated at 1 radian.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawRotatedRectangle() {
  ctx.rotate(0.5);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 50);
}

// Draw base rectangle

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 50);

// Rotate and draw second rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

drawRotatedRectangle();

// rotate and draw third rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

drawRotatedRectangle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

To fix this we modify the `drawRotatedRectangle()` function to undo all translations and rotations that it made:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawRotatedRectangle() {
  ctx.rotate(0.5);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 50);
  ctx.rotate(-0.5);
}

// Draw base rectangle

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 50);

// Rotate and draw second rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

drawRotatedRectangle();

// rotate and draw third rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

drawRotatedRectangle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now we see the red (hidden) rectangle and the green rectangle are at the same angle.

### Rotating around a different point to the origin

To demonstrate how we can rotate around a different location to the origin, we can first translate where our context origin is and then rotate our canvas. Below I move the origin to the center of the base rectangle, rotate the canvas and draw a rotated rectangle ontop of the base rectangle. Again the translations and rotations are restored in order of most recently applied.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawRotatedRectangle() {
  // Move origin to center of rectangle
  ctx.translate(30, 25);
  // Rotate 0.5 radians
  ctx.rotate(0.5);
  // Draw rectangle where the center of the rectangle is the origin
  ctx.fillRect(-30, -25, 60, 50);
  // Undo our rotate
  ctx.rotate(-0.5);
  // Undo our translate
  ctx.translate(-30, -25);
}

// Draw base rectangle

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 50);

// Rotate and draw second rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

drawRotatedRectangle();

// rotate and draw third rectangle

ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

drawRotatedRectangle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### Edit - Handling Rounding Errors

As Kaiido mentioned in the comments, the `rotate(a)` function will round the input it is given so simply doing the reverse `rotate(-a)` function will not return you to the original transformation.

The solution they suggested is to set the transformation matrix to the desired location with `setTransform()`, in these example we are only returning to the original transform of the canvas so we can use the identity matrix:

`ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`

Alternitively, you can also use `save()` and `restore()` methods. These will act like pushing the current state of the canvas context to a stack and when you `restore()` it will pop the latest state from the stack returning you to the previous transform. [This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/state.html) article by Jakob Jenkov explains this method further with some examples.

Comment: Beware though `rotate` will round your passed value, so `rotate(n); rotate(-n);` may not end up on the original rotation. If you know your current transformation, then it's better to use the absolute `setTransform` method to reset it, like here, your examples are all on the identity transform matrix, so you could just do `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` to come back to that identity matrix.

Comment: True, good spot. It's probably uselful to make use of the `save()` and `restore()` methods aswell to return to the previous transformation and state.

Comment: unfortunately save and restore will also save and restore a bunch of useless state info like styles and clipping areas etc. and thus will be slower than setTransform.